# Backing up MySQL database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have quite large and rather important DB to backup.

First off, whats best way to do it?

Secondly, easiest way I know is to export it through phpmyadmin, but, i'm worried about options, although I'm quite sure this "Add DROP DATABASE" will not drop actual databases, I'm interested what are these options for? (see pic)

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Adding DROP DATABASE will create code to drop the database before creating it. PHPMyAdmin creates backups by writing code that INSERT's the data into your DB. You can try out all the statements, PHPMyAdmin will just generate the SQL code to do the backup. You have to execute the query before something happens :)

Comment: You mean it will generate code for those along with insert code (which is backup)?
What are those for, in first place?

Comment: It will insert DROP statements before the INSERTs. Sometimes that's useful for filling up a DB with certain data before a test-run or whatever.

Comment: So it will bi used for droping db/tables in case of restoring? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but you can try out the different settings and see what difference it makes in the output SQL :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best (and IMO the only suitable) tool for backuping a MySql database is [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html)

The PhpMyAdmin options you are referring to are meant only to alter the generated statements in your dump (but will not touch your actual data). You might want to refer to this [FAQ at PhpMyAdmin](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/FAQ_6.12).

Answer (score 0):

simply create a `dump` file of your database.
`mysqldump` can be created very easily in `phpMyAdmin`.
at the home page of the database in `phpMyAdmin`, click export and select `quick` or `custom` as your choice and dump it into `sql` file format. A simple `dump` of your database would be created and then you can easily restore it again.